# How to install Karma manually?

Tags: karma-runner

I have installed Nodejs.

But I want to install Karma manully for some reason.

And there is no instruction in Karma's home page http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This installs karma globally:

```
npm install -g karma
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.But I can NOT use that cmd to install karma,because the related Phantom web site is blocked by GFW.So,I want to download Karma as a zip file or something,and then install it locally.

Comment: Are you able to access https://github.com/karma-runner/karma ? If so, click on the "Download Zip" icon. This will download a karma-master.zip file. Unzip it to obtain a karma-master directory. Then, use `npm install -g ./karma-master` to install it. But be aware that Karma has a lot of dependencies which may be pulled from sites that you cant access. You will have to figure out how obtain those packages that cannot be downloaded on your own. A good bet is to go to https://npmjs.org to search for them.